# Quantum Harmonic Oscillator density matrix in coherent states base

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, trace, quantum-statistics, coherent-states

I was trying to calculate matrix elements of the density operator for a 1D QHO (with Hamiltonian $\mathcal H = \hbar\omega a^\dagger a $) in the base of coherent states $\{\vert\alpha\rangle\}$ and noticed a discrepancy from the results in the number base representation $\{|n\rangle\}$.

In the latter, the matrix elements read
$$ \langle m|\rho|n\rangle = \frac1Z\exp(-\beta\hbar\omega n)\,\delta_{mn} $$
with $\beta=1/k_BT$ and the partition function
$$ Z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \exp(-\beta\hbar\omega n)=\frac1{1-\exp(-\beta\hbar\omega)}. $$
Now we can for example calculate the average energy
$$\langle E\rangle = -\frac{\partial \ln Z}{\partial\beta} = \frac{\hbar\omega}{\exp(\beta\hbar\omega)-1}.$$

However, when I want to evaluate the same in the coherent state base, I obtain the following results:
Using the properties of coherent states $a|\alpha\rangle=\alpha|\alpha\rangle$ and $\langle\alpha|a^\dagger=\langle\alpha|\alpha^*$, I calculate the matrix elements to
$$\langle\alpha|\rho|\alpha'\rangle = \frac1Z\exp\left(-\beta\hbar\omega\alpha^*\alpha'\right)\langle\alpha|\alpha'\rangle
= \frac1Z\exp\left(\beta\hbar\omega\alpha^*\alpha'\right)
\exp\left(-\frac12(|\alpha|^2+|\alpha'|^2)+\alpha^*\alpha'\right).$$
Calculating the trace to obtain $Z$ yields a different result than above, namely
$$Z = \frac1\pi\int\mathrm d^2\alpha\exp\left(-\beta\hbar\omega|\alpha|^2\right)
= \frac1{\beta\hbar\omega}.$$
When I'm trying to calculate the average energy, the above formula yields
$$\langle E\rangle = \frac1\beta=k_BT$$
which seems to be the classical result.

Something about the derivation in the coherent state base seems to be wrong. Where is my mistake? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The state that you are considering seems to be the thermal state. The Hamiltonian that you consider is the generic free quantum Hamiltonian with a single frequency $\omega$. The density operator of the thermal state is not in normal order. Therefore, it won't work to apply the coherent states on either side. You first need to express the density operator in normal order. That is not a trivial exercise.

Comment: The problem is that $\langle\alpha|\rho|\alpha'\rangle \neq \frac1Z\exp\left(-\beta\hbar\omega\alpha^*\alpha'\right)\langle\alpha|\alpha'\rangle$. $\langle\alpha|a^\dagger a|\alpha'\rangle=\alpha^*\alpha'\langle\alpha|\alpha'\rangle$ but if you exponetial it $a^\dagger$ is not always at the left side of $a$, e.g in the second order Talyor expansion ,$e^{-a^\dagger a}=1-a^\dagger a+\frac{1}{2} a^\dagger a a^\dagger a,$ and $\langle \alpha| a^\dagger a a^\dagger a|\alpha'\rangle\neq \alpha^{*2}\alpha'^2$.

Comment: I see, that explains it. Thanks for your help!!